# Vertical center of text in table with images

Tags: tables

I want to vertically center the text *Rule boolean behavior* in each row, how can I do this?

[Sharelatex.](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/547b70898c6ef4820beec79d#)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Rule & Sample Evolution & Boolean Form & Behavior\\
    \hline
    $Rule$  & \includegraphics{stable.png} &$boolean$ & behavior\\
    \hline
    $Rule$  & \includegraphics{decreasing.png} &$boolean$ & behavior\\
    \hline
    $Rule$  & \includegraphics{growing.png} & $ boolean $ & behavior\\
    \hline
    $Rule$  & \includegraphics{chaotic.png} &$ boolean $ & behavior\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: never use math italic for words like `$Rule$` the font is designed to make adjacent letters look like distinct variables and _not_ like a word. Use `\textit{Rule}`, and `\textit{Boolean}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace each

```
\includegraphics{stable.png}
```

by

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics{stable.png}}
```

or perhaps adjust the .5 to taste so that the reference point for the image is not on its bottom edge.

Answer (score 3):

If you add also

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

you are able to use a `valign=c` option to your `\includegraphics` command, which is easier than using `\raisebox`.

Here's an example, where I also use `booktabs` and `array` facilities for better input. For instance the first and third columns will be in italic (note `\upshape` in the header for overriding it).

The third and fourth rows show the behavior with `valign=t` and without `valign`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx} % loaded by adjustbox
\usepackage{booktabs} % better tables
\usepackage{array} % some more facilities

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\itshape}c c >{\itshape}c c}
\toprule

\upshape Rule & Sample Evolution & \upshape Boolean Form & Behavior\\

\midrule

Rule  & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=c]{duck} & boolean & behavior\\
\midrule
Rule  & \includegraphics[height=2cm,valign=t]{duck} & boolean & behavior\\
\midrule
Rule  & \includegraphics[height=2cm]{duck} & boolean & behavior\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Lorem ipsum}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]